# PHP Cookies in live server do not work but work in Local Host

Tags: php, cookies, xampp, setcookie

I have a remember me signed in button where I check if it it set I set the cookies for email and password to put them in their fields later on if the user tried to log on and destroy them if the remember me button is unchecked.

```
         if(isset($_POST["rememberme"])) { //set cookie if checkbox is checked
            setcookie ("member_ID",  $userMail, time()+ (86400));
            setcookie ("member_Password", $password, time()+ (86400));
        }else { //delete cookie if checkbox is not checked
            if(isset($_COOKIE['member_ID']) && isset($_COOKIE["member_Password"])) {
                $CookieID = $_COOKIE["member_ID"];
                $Cookiepassword = $_COOKIE["member_Password"];
                setcookie("member_ID", $CookieID, time() - 1);
                setcookie("member_Password", $Cookiepassword, time() - 1);
            }
        }
```

This is the code that puts the cookies in the user input fields

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['member_ID']) && isset($_COOKIE["member_Password"])){
    echo '
    <div class="LoginContainer">
            <form action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'" method="post">
                                    <div class="loginSpacing">
                                        <div>
                                        <label for="userID" >Email</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <input id="userID" name="userMail" required value="'.$_COOKIE['member_ID'].'"type="text">
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="loginSpacing">
                                    <div>
                                        <label for="Loginpass" >Password</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <input id="Loginpass" name="Loginpass" required value="'.$_COOKIE["member_Password"].'"type="password" data-type="password">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1" checked = "checked">
                                        <label for="rememberme" style="font-size:18px;font-size: 18px;"><span ></span> Keep me Signed in</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="SignIn-btn" value="Sign In">
                                    </div>

                                </form>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

So on the xampp local host it works perfectly. But once I posted it online its not working and I cant figure out why. I am sure of the variables $userMail and $password. What can I do or missing to make this work and if you guys have any suggestion to make the mechanism better

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you do realize that it looks like you're storing the plain-text username and password on the visitors computers? These cookies can remain there after the visitor is gone, and be picked up by anybody else.

Comment: so you recommend to use hash function for example? I'm just trying it to make it work then probably will encrypt it

Comment: Yes, hashing the password is one thing, but don't store any sensitive information in cookies. Just don't. Try to use sessions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the page Im getting redirected to I added the set cookie code from it at the top of the page it worked then